# How to add 'limit()' to $with in laravel's model?

Tags: laravel, model, eager-loading

I want to add an eager load to my model, however - I want to limit the related records.
I know how to do it using the `load(Model::class)->limit(n)` and also in the relationship method, like this: `$this->belongsTo(User::class)->limit(n)`

My problem it that I need to do it in the `$with` property. I tried many options, none worked (all failed as a code error).

My best guess is:

```
protected $with = [
        'user:id,display_name',
        'lawyer' => fn ($query) => $query->limit(4)
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cannot declare properties with dynamic values. You can either set the with property on the construction of the object.

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $with = [
        'user:id,display_name',
    ];

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->with['lawyer'] = function ($query) { $query->limit(4); };
    }
}
```

Or you could do it whenever you do the query.

```
YourModel::with(
    [
        'lawyer' => function ($query) { $query->limit(4); },
    ]
)->get();
```

Comment: I thought it was a laravel thing.. suddenly it make sense :) thanks.